# Specifying ACLs using the FAST Content API

Tags: fast-search

I'm using the deprecated content API to push data into the FAST Search Server for Sharepoint 2010 index. Migrating to BCS is on the roadmap, but in the meantime I want to add ACL information to the documents I'm pushing into the index.

I know that for the old FAST ESP server ACL information was specified using the `docacl` and `docaclsystemid` properties, but I have found no definite information regarding

- if these properties are still available in the 2010 version
- how these properties are encoded

How can I specify ACLs when when submitting documents using the FAST Content API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docacl` is still persisted in 2010, but appropriate managed property has `[SummaryType]` set to `Disabled`. To see the value of this property you must set `SummaryType` to `Static` or `Dynamic`. I don't know how they encoded, usually single value looks like this:

```
winaecqaaaaaaaakfiaaaadf4pmsee5mubf43xwubpiamaaa
```

you can extract value of this property using powershell ([Get-FASTSearchSecurityEncodedSid](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff393821.aspx), [Get-FASTSearchSecurityDecodedSid](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff393823.aspx)) or .net code. Some more info [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dark_corners/archive/2012/04/03/fast-search-for-sharepoint-2010-item-level-security-using-fast-search-jdbc-database-connector.aspx).

If using content api, you can specify acl in this way:

```
//To allow access for specic groups/users, the NTAccount class can be used
string userName = @"username|group";
NTAccount account = new NTAccount(userName);
SecurityIdentifier sid = (SecurityIdentifier)account.Translate(typeof(SecurityIdentifier));
DiscretionaryAcl dacl = new DiscretionaryAcl(false, false, 1);
dacl.AddAccess(AccessControlType.Allow, sid, 0x7, InheritanceFlags.None, PropagationFlags.None);
CommonSecurityDescriptor sd = new CommonSecurityDescriptor(false, false, ControlFlags.DiscretionaryAclPresent,
                                                              sid, sid, null, dacl);
doc.SecurityDescriptor = sd.GetSddlForm(AccessControlSections.All);
```

or

```
doc.SecurityDescriptor = Document.VISIBLE_TO_ALL;
```

to make it visible to all users. This code is from samples of content api for fast search for sharepoint.